# annotation() and text() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, annotations

I wonder what is the difference between `annotation()` and `text()` functions in Matlab? In what cases are one of them preferred over the other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[TEXT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) positions text in relation to axes. In contrast, [ANNOTATION](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/annotation.html) position is figure-related. ANNOTATION can put on figure not only text, but lines, shapes, arrows, etc.
Consequently, TEXT takes axes handles as an argument (or gca for current axes), and ANNOTATION takes figure handles (or gcf for current figure).

Answer (score 1):

Also, notice that they create different objects with different properties.
So for example, while TEXT objects can be rotated with the ROTATION property, ANNOTATION objects lack this property and cannot be rotated.