# MATLAB textbox in a constant position on top of spinning 3D plot?

Tags: matlab, text, 3d, location, figure

I'm trying to have a textbox in MATLAB on a spinning plot, but I don't want the textbox to change its position relative to the figure.  I thought that `'units','normalized'` in the `text` function would do it, but it's not quite working, as the example below illustrates.  I suppose I could use `uicontrol` but I'd like to use Greek letters and I can't get `uicontrol` looking quite as good as `text`.  The following example recreates my problem.  You'll notice the text box moves as the plot spins, but I'd like it to just stay in the top left region where it starts.  Thank you!

```
part_x = rand(1000,3)-.5;                         %generate random 3D coordinates to scatter
fig1 = figure;
scatter3(part_x(:,1), part_x(:,2), part_x(:,3))
axis equal vis3d
axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1])
set(fig1,'color','w')

for tau = 1:150
    view(tau+20,30);                              %spin the plot
    pause(.01)
    if tau~=1; delete(tau_text); end;             %delete the previous text if it exists
    tau_text = text(.1,.7,...
                    ['\tau = ',num2str(tau)],...
                    'units','normalized',...      %text coordinates relative to figure?
                    'Margin',3,...                %these last 3 lines make it look nice
                    'edgecolor','k',...
                    'backgroundcolor','w');
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1) As you found out - using an [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) object instead of `text` object is the way to go. The difference is explained very nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678563/annotation-and-text-in-matlab).

2) You should only create the `annotation` once and then modify its string instead of deleting and recreating it on every iteration.

Finally:

```
part_x = rand(1000,3)-.5;
fig1 = figure;
scatter3(part_x(:,1), part_x(:,2), part_x(:,3))
axis equal vis3d
axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1])
set(fig1,'color','w')

%// Create the text outside the loop:
tau_text = annotation('textbox',[0.2 0.8 0.1 0.05],...
                  'string','\tau = NaN',...
                  'Margin',4,... 
                  'edgecolor','k',...
                  'backgroundcolor','w',...
                  'LineWidth',1);

for tau = 1:150
    view(tau+20,30); 
    pause(.01)
    set(tau_text,'String',['\tau = ',num2str(tau)]); %// Modify the string
end
```

Notes:

1) It is interesting to note that @Otto's suggestion of using `legend` results in the creation of an *axes* (because this is what a `legend` object is - an `axes` with `annotation` children). You could then position the legend manually, and get its location using either `get(gco,'position')` (assuming it was the last thing you clicked) or more generally `get(findobj('tag','legend'),'position')`. Afterwards, whenever you create the legend, you can just set its `position` to the one you previously got. You could also get rid of the line\marker inside the legend by deleting the appropriate `child` of type `line` from the `legend`, e.g.:

```
ezplot('sin(x)');
hLeg = legend('\tauex\tau');
delete(findobj(findobj('Tag','legend'),'Type','line'));
hA1 = findobj(findobj('Tag','legend'),'Type','text');
set(hA1,'Position',[0.5,0.5,0],'HorizontalAlignment','center');
```

It is of course also possible to manipulate the legend's `String` using its handle (`hA1`) directly.

2) [This post on UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/pinning-annotations-to-graphs) discusses the behavior of `annotation` objects and some undocumented ways to manipulate them.

Comment: +1 thanks for the link to Yair's website that's good to know!

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
legend(['\tau = ',num2str(tau)],'Location','NorthWestOutside')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dev-iL!  `annotation` works much better for this purpose than `text` and the implementation is very similar.  And thank you for the advice on modifying the string rather than deleting an recreating it.

Here is the code now, working much better:

```
part_x = rand(1000,3)-.5;                         %generate random 3D coordinates to scatter
fig1 = figure;
scatter3(part_x(:,1), part_x(:,2), part_x(:,3))
axis equal vis3d
axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1])
set(fig1,'color','w')

tau_text = annotation('textbox',[0.2 0.8 0.1 0.05],...
                      'string','',...
                      'Margin',4,...                %these last 4 lines make it look nice
                      'edgecolor','k',...
                      'backgroundcolor','w',...
                      'LineWidth',1);

for tau = 1:150
    view(tau+20,30);                              %spin the plot
    pause(.01)
    set(tau_text,'String',['\tau = ',num2str(tau)]);
end
```

Comment: Seeing how you didn't accept your own (working) answer, I incorporated your answer into my own and added a small discussion of `legend`.